# transact SQL, sum each row and insert into another table

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

for a table on ms-sql2000 containing the following columns and numbers:

```
S_idJ_id    Se_id   B_id    Status  Count   multiply
63  1000    16  12  1   10  2       
64  1001    12  16  1   9   3       
65  1002    17  12  1   10  2       
66  1003    16  12  1   6   3       
67  1004    12  16  1   10  2
```

I want to generate an classic asp script which will do the following for each row
where status=1 :

-multiply   -> answer= multiply column 'count' with column 'multiply'

Then:

count the total answer and sum for each se_id like :

```
se_id   total
12      47
16      38
17      20
```

and display on screen like

```
Rank    se_id   total
1       12      47
2       16      38
3       17      20
```

Condition:
if there are multiple equal total values then give the lower numbered `se_id` a priority for
getting a ranking and give the next higher numbered `se_id` the next number in rank

Any sample code in classic asp or advice is welcome on how to get this accomplished

Comment: I don't think it's really related to classic ASP.. anyway what you got so far?

Comment: i got only theory at this stage - i was reading sql book on sql server using transact sql only for this matter. it could be done without asp

Comment: corrected my question so it is asp only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'score' = source table.

```
if (EXISTS (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'result_table')) 
begin
  drop table result_table;
end

select 
  rank = IDENTITY(INT,1,1), 
  se_id, sum(multiply * count) as total
into result_table
from score
where status = 1
group by se_id
order by total desc, se_id;
```

[Edit] Change query as answer on first comment

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help you. It's customary to accept the answer by clicking the tick mark icon by the post.